# How to insert vector of ones to Matrix?

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I've a vector and a matrix:

```
1
1

0 0
0 0
```

I want to prepend the vector to matrix to produce :

```
1 0 0
1 0 0
```

I have so far :

```
val dv = DenseVector(1.0,1.0);
val dm = DenseMatrix.zeros[Double](2,2)
```

Reading the API : http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/#breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix
and both these docs : 
https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstart https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Linear-Algebra-Cheat-Sheet

But this operation does not appear to be available ?

Is there a method/function to prepend a vector of ones to a Matrix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option here. Firstly convert the *DenseVector* to a *2X1* matrix and then use the *DenseMatrix.horzcat()* method:

```
val newMat = DenseMatrix.horzcat(new DenseMatrix(2,1,dv.toArray), dm)

# breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] = 1.0  0.0  0.0  
#                                     1.0  0.0  0.0

newMat.rows
# 2
newMat.cols
# 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a function to create your dense matrix with a column of ones prepended:

```
def prependOnesColumn[V](original: DenseMatrix[V]): DenseMatrix[V] = {
  val ones = DenseMatrix.ones(original.rows, 1)
  val dataWithOnes = ones.data ++ original.data
  DenseMatrix.create(original.rows, original.cols + 1, dataWithOnes)
}
```

Comment: Psidom's answer looks like the idiomatic way of concatenating any number of matrices with breeze's library.